# SSIS 2017 Upgrade issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

We are upadating the packages(packages are in package deployment model) from SSIS 2012 to SSIS 2017. There are lots of script components in all the packages. When we are upgrading the packages we are having an error

Description: CS0234 - The type or namespace name 'Dts' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?), ScriptMain.cs, 14, 26 End Error

Configurations:
SQLserver 2017 
Visual studio enterprise 2015 + SSDT 2015

We have tried different options of deleting and re-adding the assemble file in the script component. Looks like the Microsoft.Sqlserver.ManagedDts assemble file is having issues for 2017 version. When we upgrade the packages to SSIS 2016 the packages work fine.

When we try to run the SSIS 2016 packages from Sqlserver agent job in SQLSERVER 2017 it is trying to upgrade the packages to 2017 and throw up the similar error as above.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a mix of straight SSIS and BIML generated packages all suffering the same issues. Again, struggling for answers

We did find a workaround, but it's far from ideal :

1. View code on the dtsx package
2. Find the Project node
3. Find the PropertyGroup node which contains the AssemblyName node
4. Add a TargetFrameworkVersion to this PropertyGroup, with a value of v4.5
5. Save

Now if you open the package you can build/Execute your package

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes the above solution is solving the issue but as you have mentioned it's far from the ideal solution as we have hundreds of script components in our packages. We have received a similar solution from Microsoft forums but hopefully they solve this issue via an update to the SSDT.

Comment: I've asked the question on MSDN too, maybe you can give it a bump ;) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f45732a8-1585-4d18-a1fa-229cd5310a87/the-type-or-namespace-name-dts-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace?forum=vsta

Answer (score 0):

I'd forgotten about this post, but just for some extra info Varigence supplied us with a pre-release of the next cut of the BIML language (around 2018-05-25) and our issues (at least the automated package build ones) had gone away